# Randomize UIImageViews through code

Tags: uiimageview, creation

I have 8 images on my View. 4 on left n 4 on right side on the view. i need to match images every time from ones on left to ones on right. I have done this statically by creating 8 image views in the interface builder and connecting it to the outlets created. Now i have to dynamically randomize the image views so tat the match doesn't become obvious. like for the 1st left topmost imageview the match will always be at the bottom most in the right side image view. i tried creating image views in 2 formats

UIImageView *image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRect(111, 135,140,130)];
image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iMac.png"

also

UIImageView *image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iMac.png"]];
image1.frame = CGRect(111,135,140,130);

images are not displayed on the screen at all. Please correct me if i have gone wrong in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Replace

```
image1.frame = CGRect(111,135,140,130);
```

with

```
image1.frame = CGRectMake(111,135,140,130);
```